# How do I tell what parts of Boost have been deprecated?

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, deprecated, boost-phoenix

I'm just starting to use boost for my embedded C++ programming. Lambda looked interesting so I was reading up on it. When I tried using stl algorithms with lambdas on containers of shared_ptrs I ran into some problems. Doing some searching here on SO led me to a post that indicated Lambda was deprecated and Phoenix was to be used for all new code.  As I try to learn more of boost I would like to avoid learning the deprecated parts. Where is this type of thing documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the boost documentation will warn you of deprecated features. However, this information sometimes "leaks" out before the docs are updated, which is what seems to have happened in this case. You could always subscribe to one of the developer mailing lists if you really want to be at the cutting-edge, otherwise you should be just fine sticking to the official docs.